# Limit maximum concurrent ssh connections per user does not work when shell is /sbin/nologin

Tags: linux, ssh, centos7

I have a Centos 7 server and when I limit the maximum connections per user using the config file /etc/security/limits.conf it works just fine. See below an example of my configuration in that file:

```
@users -   maxlogins   1
```

However, if the shell associated with the user is `/sbin/nologin`, it does not work. I created some users that are used only for port forwarding. Since I want to restrict rights for these users as much as I can, I assigned them the shell `/sbin/nologin`.

also, I changed these lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
MaxSessions 1
MaxStartups 1
```

but this does not help.

So, is there a workaround for this issue? What I want is to limit the maximum connections for these users too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you try to add in `limits.conf` line with `maxsyslogins`    set to 1?

Comment: Also do you have in sshd_config PAM line like: `session    required   pam_limits.so`?

Comment: `maxsyslogins` not works and there is no option in sshd_config to control session per user.

Comment: sshd_config **PAM** record

Comment: setting `session    required   pam_limits.so`  not work. because we receive two connections from one username, restricting sessions does not work for this scenario.